# Corregir error no instance(s) of type variable(s) X exist so that LiveData<List<Repo>> conforms to LiveData<X>

Tags: java, android

I'm doing a test application and the example I am following uses Java functions in Visual Studio to receive a list of integers and return a `LiveData`. Everything was OK up to this point, but when I write the example syntax it gives me the following error:

```
no instance(s) of type variable(s) X exist so that LiveData<List<Repo>> conforms to LiveData<X>
```

I understand that it must be a version problem of Android Studio. Or it could be that it is written differently?
This is the code I am trying to use which gives me the error:

```
public LiveData<List<Repo>> loadOrdered(List<Integer> repoIds) {
    SparseIntArray order = new SparseIntArray();
    int index = 0;
    for (Integer repoId : repoIds) {
        order.put(repoId, index++);
    }
    return Transformations.map(loadById(repoIds), new Function<List<Repo>, List<Repo>>() {
        @Override
        public List<Repo> apply(List<Repo> repositories) {
            Collections.sort(repositories, new Comparator<Repo>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Repo o1, Repo o2) {
                    int pos1 = order.get(o1.id);
                    int pos2 = order.get(o2.id);
                    return pos1 - pos2;
                }
            });
            return repositories;
        }
    });
```

I leave the declaration of this function:

```
loadById(repoIds):
        @Query("SELECT * FROM Repo WHERE id in(:repoIds)")
        protected abstract LiveData<List<Repo>> loadById(List<Integer> repoIds);
```

This is the `Repo` class:

```
@Entity(indices = {@Index("id"), @Index("owner_login")},
        primaryKeys = {"name", "owner_login"})
public class Repo {

    public final int id;
    @SerializedName("name")
    public  final String name;
    @SerializedName("full_name")
    public  final String fullName;
    @SerializedName("description")
    public  final String description;
    @SerializedName("stargazers_count")
    public  final String stars;
    @SerializedName("owner")
    @Embedded(prefix = "owner_")
    public final Owner owner;

    public Repo(int id, String name, String fullName, String description, String stars, Owner owner) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.description = description;
        this.stars = stars;
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    public static class Owner{
        @SerializedName("login")
        public  final String login;
        @SerializedName("url")
        public final String url;

        public Owner(String login, String url) {
            this.login = login;
            this.url = url;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally this the `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    namespace 'com.example.arquitecturamvvm'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.arquitecturamvvm"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.3.2'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is Java, not Kotlin. You probably want to tag Android since that's what it's primarily about.

Comment: Can you show the code of the `loadById()` method? What is its return type?

Comment: @Query("SELECT * FROM Repo WHERE id in(:repoIds)")
        protected abstract LiveData<List<Repo>> loadById(List<Integer> repoIds); @Tenfour04

Comment: @Tenfour04 
This is the version of Android Studio that I have installed: Android Studio Flammngo | 2022.2.1

Comment: `return Transformations.map(loadById(repoIds), (Function1<List<Repo>, List<Repo>>) repositories -> {
            repositories.sort(new Comparator<Repo>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Repo o1, Repo o2) {
                    int pos1 = order.get(o1.id);
                    int pos2 = order.get(o2.id);
                    return pos1 - pos2;
                }
            });
            return repositories;
        });`

Comment: For future reference, tag [tag:android] instead of [tag:android-studio] for questions about Android development. Android Studio's tag is for questions specifically about the IDE so there are far fewer people watching that tag and it's not really relevant to questions like this. If you tag Android, a lot more people will see your question. If you had tagged `android` and `java` to begin with, you probably would have had an answer within minutes. And don't tag Kotlin unless you are fine with answers that have only Kotlin examples in them.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument for the `map` method is a `Function1`, not a `Function`. But you wouldn't have to worry about this if you're using lambdas, which is the intended way to use it, and much more concise/readable:

```java
public LiveData<List<Repo>> loadOrdered(List<Integer> repoIds) {
    SparseIntArray order = new SparseIntArray();
    int index = 0;
    for (int repoId : repoIds) { // might as well avoid boxing
        order.put(repoId, index++);
    }
    return Transformations.map(
        loadById(repoIds),
        repositories -> {
            Collections.sort(repositories, Comparator.comparingInt(repo -> order.get(repo.id)));
            return repositories;
        }
    );
}
```